# how to stop parent request if clicked child angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have similar code like below and I want If I clicked in Child Div then Parent Div click event should not trigger.

```
<div class="parentDiv" (click)="parentDiv()">
   <div class="childDiv" (click)="childDiv()">Child Container</div>
</div>
```

When I am clicking on "***childDiv***" so first it triggers "**parentDiv()**" event and then "**childDiv()**" event.

Can you please help me to resolve it?

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where you need  `event.stopPropagation();`

```
<div class="childDiv" (click)="childDiv(event)">Child Container</div>
```

And

```
childDiv(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
}
```

What happening in your case is called propagation of events.

When you click on child div, the click event propagates to parent div. You need to stop that propagation.

Above is the way to do it.

Or if you want a one line solution this it

```
<div class="childDiv"
 (click)="childDiv(event);$event.stopPropagation()" >Child Container</div>
```

Comment: @AmbujKhanna Glad to know that. Please consider accepting this answer

Answer (score 3):

## [Stopping bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#stopping-bubbling)

A bubbling event goes from the target element straight up. Normally it goes upwards till `<html>`, and then to document object, and some events even reach window, calling all handlers on the path.

But any handler may decide that the event has been fully processed and stop the bubbling.

The method for it is `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
<div class="parentDiv" (click)="parentDiv()">
   <div class="childDiv" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Child Container</div>
</div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
function parentDiv() {
  alert('parent div')
}
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv" onclick="parentDiv()">Parent Div
  <div class="childDiv" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Child Container</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.stopPropagation();` in the function attached to the `.childDiv`

In Javascript there is something called Event Bubbling; when an event fires for one element it fires for all of it's parent elements as well.

Heres a code snippet displaying the code needed

```js
document.getElementById("parentDiv").addEventListener("click", function (e){
  alert('parentDiv clicked');
});

document.getElementById("childDiv").addEventListener("click", function (e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('childDiv clicked');
});
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
  Parent Container
   <div id="childDiv">Child Container</div>
</div>
```